# Should I keep a global shared component, or using one per child?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

### My App:

I am implementing a React Native application where a `FlatList` is used to display each item fullscreen. Each may contain/display several things, like Text, Images, GIFs. Also, some sound/song may be played. Think of this like a "enhanced" gallery/carousel.

My actual implementation is something like:

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {

    this.state = {
      currentIndex: null //currentIndex gets updated when displayed FlatList item changes
    };

   // Black magic here to update currentIndex

   render() {
      const data = [{image: "...", text: "...", sound: "..."}, {...},...]
      return ( 
          <FlatList
            data = {data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              const isDisplayed = this.state.currentIndex === index;
              return <Thing {...item} isDisplayed={isDisplayed} />;
            }}       
            ...
          />
   }
}
```

The `Thing` component is something similar to:

```
export default class Thing extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isDisplayed){
       <SoundComponent sound={this.props.sound}/>
       <View>
            <Text> this.props.text</Text>
            <Image> this.props.image</Image>
       </View>
    }

}
```

### My question:

Should I keep one `SoundComponent` per `Thing`, or should I use one global `SoundComponent` managed by and inside `App`? On one side I think that `App` should be unaware of how `data` is used, on the other side one centralized `SoundComponent` seems easier to orchestrate one sound at the time.

**Notice that only one sound can be played at the same time.**

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any kind of "global" component in React. Every component has to be imported or passed as a prop. You have a few options if you want to avoid adding an import to each file though:

1) Create a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that renders the PageContent and the wrapped component.

```
import PageContent from './PageContent';

const withPageContent = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <PageContent>
          <WrappedComponent />
        </PageContent>
      )
    }
  }
};

export default withPageContent;
```

// Usage

```
import withPageContent from './withPageContent';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withPageContent(MyComponent);
```

2) Pass PageContent as a prop to a component:

```
import PageContent from './PageContent';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child1 content={PageContent} />
        <Child2 content={PageContent} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

// Usage

```
export default class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const PageContent = this.props.content;
    return (
      <PageContent>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </PageContent>
    )
  }
}

export default class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const PageContent = this.props.content;
    return (
      <PageContent>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </PageContent>
    )
  }
}
```